# How to use 'HTML Copy' feature of 'Productivity Power Tools 2013' extension?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

Simply as that, I've verified that the `HTML Copy` feature is enabled at the options of my `Productivity Power Tools` extension installation but I can't see any context-menu option like "*Copy as HTML*" or something else, then how can be used this feature?

It's a nightmare to find a kind of *HTML-Formatting* extension for a VB.NET programmer, all the extensions that I've seen only works for C# like `Code4blog` extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the *Copy HTML Markup* command from the *Edit* menu